# Grant Network Service permission to recycle iis app pool

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I am trying to create a .NET web application that restarts an app pool on a remote web server, running IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003. I have the code working, but I have a permissions issue.

```
string appPoolPath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ApplicationPool"];

string systemId = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

try
{

    DirectoryEntry svc = new DirectoryEntry(appPoolPath);
    svc.Invoke("Recycle");
    LabelResult.Text = "Application Pool Recycled Succesfully!";
    LabelResult.Visible = true;
}
catch(Exception exc)
{

    LabelResult.Text = "Error (" + systemId + "): " + exc.Message + " : " + exc.InnerException;

    LabelResult.Visible = true;
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

Error (NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. : System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

So my question is, how can I grant the NETWORK SERVICE account permission to invoke recycle without giving the account full admin privileges?  Is it possible?

I know another way to solve this is to impersonate one of the existing admins on the server, but I am not allowed to do that.  I can't create users on the machine and I can't get login credentials for existing user accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

Put a dummy file in /bin directory, and update it everytime you want to restart the pool

Comment: that restarts the app, not the app pool

Answer (score 2):

This is not entirely true.
You need a section in Web.Config:

```
<section name="TestSection" restartOnExternalChanges="true" requirePermission="false" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration"/>

<TestSection configSource="Test.config"></TestSection>
```

Then when you modify Test.config, the app pool gets recycled.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove and create application pool. Has solved my problem.

```
var server = new ServerManager();
var pool = server.ApplicationPools.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Name == "MyPool");
if (pool != null)
{
    server.ApplicationPools.Remove(pool);
    server.CommitChanges();

    server.ApplicationPools.Add("MyPool");
    server.CommitChanges();
}
```